# Quill JavaScript Rich Text Editor restrict tags

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, quill

I'm trying to use  Quill JavaScript Rich Text Editor. I need to configure it to use only a predefined tag set:

```
b, i, pre, a, br + Emoji
```

Right now I have configured it in the following way:

```
var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
Block.tagName = 'PRE';
Quill.register(Block, true);

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: true
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

As you may see I already have changed the wrapper to `PRE` tag. How to also configure Quill to use the mentioned restricted tag set? No other tags can be allowed and must be automatically removed if present.

Comment: Sidenote: you will still need to sanitise or validate the final HTML on the server; just white/blacklisting tags in Quill doesn't guarantee anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `formats` in the parameters of the constructor, there you can define which formats you want to support.

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  formats: ['bold', 'italic', 'code', 'code-block', 'link'],
  ...
});
```

Comment: Copy pasting bold text from word is not working. I have  modules: {
            toolbar: false
        }, since we do not want toolbar

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of all formats:

```
 formats = [
    // 'background',
    'bold',
    // 'color',
    // 'font',
    // 'code',
    'italic',
    // 'link',
    // 'size',
    // 'strike',
    // 'script',
    'underline',
    // 'blockquote',
    // 'header',
    // 'indent',
    'list',
    // 'align',
    // 'direction',
    // 'code-block',
    // 'formula'
    // 'image'
    // 'video'
  ];
```

You can use this to prevent some formats.

Answer (score 1):

Quill works with [Delta](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) and [formats](https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/), not directly with HTML and tags.
You can set the [formats](https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#formats) config option to limit the allowed formats.